# Recursively send e-mail while updating sql table

Tags: php, mysql, email, send

I have the following query :

```
UPDATE
    users AS t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
          user
        FROM
               facebook, users
        WHERE
            facebook.user = users.id
        GROUP BY
           users.id
    ) AS m ON
        m.user = t.id
SET
   t.coins =t.coins+200
WHERE
  m.user = t.id
```

I need help to create a php script which must actually send an email to the users I update the number of coins. The email field is in users table.

Thank you!

Comment: Send e-mail from your database? Then we should know **WHAT** database (and which version) you use. Or from your application? Well then we need to know **WHAT** programming language you're using and how you want to send the e-mails...

Comment: I need a php script using mail() function. The version of MySQL client is 5.5.23. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Select all rows you need:

```
SELECT
t.id, t.email
FROM
    users AS t
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
          user
        FROM
               facebook, users
        WHERE
            facebook.user = users.id
        GROUP BY
           users.id
    ) AS m ON
        m.user = t.id
WHERE
  m.user = t.id
```

and then update every row in PHP loop where you also can send your mail.

**UPDATE**

So let imagine `$result` is var with result array.

```
foreach($result as $res){
    $sql = 'UPDATE users SET coins = coins+200 WHERE id = '.$res['id'];
    mail(/*WITH YOUR PARAMS*/); //email in $res['email'];
}
```

Comment: Do you write any mysql query with PHP?

Comment: If you worked with php/mysql then you can get array of results from query I wrote. I udate my answer with other part.